# How can I uncheck a checkbox Shared Preference when the device gets restarted?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have a checkbox in my shared preferences.
I want to uncheck it only after my device gets restarted (Or being shut down and powered up).
How can I do that ?
I've tried to use Broadcast Receiver like this:

```
<receiver android:name="android.dunk.services.MyBroadcastReceiver" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
</receiver>
```

and added this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

In the manifest tag.

And in my broadcast receiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action != null)
            {
                SharedPreferences sp = ((Activity) context).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);               
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("myCheckBox", false);
                        editor.commit();
            }
}
```

Comment: you forget to call `editor.commit()`

Comment: added. still does not work

Comment: try this `SharedPreferences sp =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);` btw you are talking about the check box of `PreferenceActivity` ??

Comment: yes. My class extends from PreferenceActivity and implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

Comment: then above line should work.

Comment: Still doesn't. Is there anyway to debug it ? After I restart my device, then my eclipse detach from the process because the device isn't connected anymore

Comment: Look at the logcat after the device boots and see my answer.

Comment: sow a simple `Toast` in `onRecive`? and if code came in this section or not

Comment: ok. I've put toast in the first line of the method and it doesn't show when I restart my device, and even after I start my application.

Answer (score 0):

The `Context` that is passed to `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` is not an `Activity`, so this line should throw a `CastClassException` (which you should see in the logcat):

```
SharedPreferences sp = ((Activity) context).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

You need to use the methods of `Context` to access the preferences. Try this:

```
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

`name` should be the name of your package (ie: `com.myname.myapp`)

Comment: tried that and it doesn't work. It seems like the application doesn't reach that piece of code.
This is the only thing I see in my LogCat:
"Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory"

Comment: Starting with Android 3.0, your application will NOT get the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast unless the user has run it at least once since installation (or since the user did a "force stop"). If you install your app on the phone and then just boot the phone (without first starting your application), it will **not** see the BOOT_COMPLETE event. Is that what you are seeing?